# Problems with DataGridView in C# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm having a problem with DataGridView.

First, as you can see:
I'm transferring information from `DataGridView` to `Info_Goods` array.
I checked it carefully, it completely transferred all the information I need.

But when I use `foreach` to write the information of `Info_Goods` array to `text.txt`, only the information of the first row gets written.
I created a different array, name `testArray` with some elements are created before

example:

```
string[,] testArray = {{a,b,c}, {d,e,f}};
```

It wrote completely the information of testArray.
I don't know what happened.

```
string Name = "";
Name = tb_Name.Text;

string[,] Info_Goods = new string[50, 50];

int Number = 1;

for (int i = 0; i < dgv_Input.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
  for (int j = 0; j < dgv_Input.Columns.Count - 1; j++)
  {
    Info_Goods[i, j] = dgv_Input.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
  }
}

////================================ Write File 
 // string[,] test = { { "a", "b", "c" }, { "d", "e", "f" } };  // it worked
using (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(Number.ToString() + " " + Name + ".txt"))
{
  foreach (string s in Info_Goods)      // it didn't worked
  {
    sw.WriteLine(s);
  }
}
```

Second, I want to check empty elements in DataGridView and show an error notification.

As you can see, I'm using a loop same as what I used when I transferred information from DataGridView to `Info_Goods` array .

I used 1 check variable (1: empty elements and 0: not empty). It didn't work

But when I only wrote the IF statement (not using loops), It worked.

```
int check = 0;

for (int a = 0; a < dgv_Input.Rows.Count - 1; a++)
{
  for (int b = 0; b < dgv_Input.Columns.Count - 1; b++)
  {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dgv_Input.Rows[a].Cells[b].Value as string))   // it didn't work
    {
      check = 1;
    }
  }
}
// if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dgv_Input.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value as string)) // it worked
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first code, it is unclear why you are using a string array of [50,50]? The `DataGridView` `dgv_Input` would seem like a better way to size the array. Or better yet use a list. Using the array the way you are will create null values for numerous elements in the array or a possible overflow. Let’s say there are 4 columns and 5 rows of data in the `dgv_Input`, The string[50,50] array will look like below after you read the cells into the array as the code does:

```
[0,0] data0 col1
[0,1] data0 col2
[0,2] data0 col3
[0,3] data0 col4
[0,4] null
[0,5] null
[0,6] null
   …….
[0,47] null
[0,48] null
[0,49] null
[1,0] data1 col1
[1,1] data1 col2
[1,2] data1 col3
[1,3] data1 col4
[1,4] null
[1,5] null
[1,6] null
```

This is clearly a lot of wasted space and a guarantee for null values/strings. When you are trying to write this array to a file you should check for these null values with:

```
If (s != null)…
```

You may want to rethink how you want to store the strings from the `DataGridView`… I am guessing 1 string for each row and possibly store them in a `List` since you may not know how many here are.

For your second problem I am guessing the issue is with the following line of code:

```
string.IsNullOrEmpty(dgv_Input.Rows[a].Cells[b].Value as string)
```

I do not think this is returning what you are expecting. First, there is a good possibility that `dgv_Input.Rows[a].Cells[b].Value` may be null. I am aware that the line appears to be asking if the STRING of a null value `IsNullOrEmpty`. Also the line above will return true if the value in the DataGridView cell is a number. In other words, the line above does not seem to work as expected. Below I broke the code down to check which values are null or which values are empty strings. This appears to work as expected

```
for (int a = 0; a < dataGridView1.Rows.Count -1 ; a++) {
  for (int b = 0; b < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; b++) {
    if (dataGridView1.Rows[a].Cells[b].Value != null) {
      if (dataGridView1.Rows[a].Cells[b].Value.ToString() != "") {
        textBox1.Text += dataGridView1.Rows[a].Cells[b].Value.ToString() + ",";
      } else {
       // MessageBox.Show("String is empty: ");
      }
    } else {
      //MessageBox.Show("DGV Cell Value is null: ");
    }
  }
  textBox1.Text += Environment.NewLine;
}
```

Comment: following the way tomato32 give to me, I fixed that error of 2nd problem. But I am very thankful for your help and the knowledge you shared , I just want to say Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You should modify the loop as below. And then it will run properly, my friend.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgv_Input.Rows.Count; i++)
{
  for (int j = 0; j < dgv_Input.Columns.Count; j++)
  {
    Info_Goods[i, j] = dgv_Input.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
  }
}
```

Comment: I dont know why but it help me to solve my 2nd problem, thank you so much bro. But I think that way doesnt work with my 1st problem because in my datagridview, the last column is button and the last row is an empty row, so that why i used "dgv_Input.Rows.Count - 1 and dgv_Input.Columns.Count - 1 " instead of "dgv_Input.Rows.Count and dgv_Input.Columns.Count"

Comment: Are you building a application for editable grid view, right? And then, when click button, show validate?

Comment: Same as that. My idea is if i click the button , a row will be deleted. But I will build that feature later . Now  I have to find the way how to write all values of Info_Goods array to a text.txt because it just writes only 1 element of that array :((  *sosad*

Comment: You use skype? Just add my nick, manhtran32. Maybe I can support :))

Comment: trời đất người việt à , sao ko dùng tiếng việt luôn đi rep comment đi anh :)). Mà em không có máy nên chỉ ra quán code thôi anh ơi